# How can I replace one element in a Vec of string slices with a newly formatted String?

Tags: rust

I am trying to replace one line in a list of string slices, and fail to make it correctly with lifetimes.

Here is my code:

```rust
pub struct SomeDataType<'a> {
    pub lines: Vec<&'a str>,
    // other fields omitted
}

impl<'a> SomeDataType<'a> {
    pub fn parse(text: &str) -> Result<SomeDataType, String> {
        let lines: Vec<&str> = text.lines().collect();
        Ok(SomeDataType { lines })
    }

    // replace first occurrence, and return original value
    pub fn replace_placeholder(&mut self, real_value: &str) -> Option<String> {
        let newstr = format!("## {}", real_value);
        for line in self.lines.iter_mut() {
            if line.starts_with("## PLACEHOLDER") {
                let original: String = String::from(*line);
                *line = newstr.as_str();
                return Some(original);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let text = r##"
Lorem ipsum
## PLACEHOLDER 1
dolor sit amet,
## PLACEHOLDER 2
consectetur adipiscing elit,
"##;

    let mut x = SomeDataType::parse(text).unwrap();
    let original = x.replace_placeholder("The Real Value");
    println!("ORIGINAL VALUE: {:?}", original); //prints: ORIGINAL VALUE: Some("## PLACEHOLDER 1")
    println!("{}", x.lines.join("\n")) //prints the text with first occurrence replaced
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `newstr` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:25
   |
6  | impl<'a> SomeDataType<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
18 |                 *line = newstr.as_str();
   |                 --------^^^^^^---------
   |                 |       |
   |                 |       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 assignment requires that `newstr` is borrowed for `'a`
...
23 |     }
   |     - `newstr` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This must be something with borrowing and lifetimes, but I could not figure out what it is.

Comment: that not possible with your current code `newstr` get out of the scope. Maybe you want to use `Cow` instead of `&'a str` or more simple just use `String`

Comment: @Stargateur can you elaborate it? I used `Cow` for `newstr` without success; and right now, it is a `String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data structure

```
pub struct SomeDataType<'a> {
    lines: Vec<&'a str>,
}
```

stores *references* to string slices. Since in Rust references must always be valid, these string slices need to live longer than the instance of `SomeDataType`, and the lifetime of each string slice must be at least `'a`.

Your function `replace_placeholder()` creates a new local `String` instance in this line:

```
let newstr = format!("## {}", real_value);
```

This `String` instance only lives for the runtime of the function, since it is a local variable. To be able to store a reference to this string in `self.lines`, it would at least have to live for the lifetime `'a` of `SomeDataType`, which is doesn't. This is why the compiler complains.

With your current data structure, you can't really make this work. Any string you create in `replace_placeholder()` will only live for the runtime of the function, unless you can pass ownership of the string to a longer-lived data structure. `SomeDataType` cannot take ownership, though – it only stores references.

The easiest solution is to change your data type definition to

```
pub struct SomeDataType {
    lines: Vec<String>,
}
```

so it owns all strings. This will require you to create new `String` objects from the lines you parse, so you will copy all lines. This is unlikely to be a problem, but if for some reason you need to avoid this overhead, you can also use a vector of `Cow<'a, str>`. This data structure is able to store either a reference or an owned string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I made the code work by updating it to use `Cow` as Sven Marnach and Stargateur recommended:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub struct SomeDataType<'a> {
    pub lines: Vec<Cow<'a, str>>,
    // other fields omitted
}

impl<'a> SomeDataType<'a> {
    pub fn parse(text: &str) -> Result<SomeDataType, String> {
        let lines = text.lines().map(Cow::Borrowed).collect();
        Ok(SomeDataType { lines })
    }

    // replace first occurrence, and return original
    pub fn replace_placeholder(&mut self, real_value: &str) -> Option<String> {
        let newstr = Cow::Owned(format!("## {}", real_value));
        for line in self.lines.iter_mut() {
            if line.starts_with("## PLACEHOLDER") {
                let original: String = String::from(line.clone());
                *line = newstr;
                return Some(original);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using `String` seems even simpler, and is probably also more elegant:

```rust
pub struct SomeDataType {
    pub lines: Vec<String>,
    // other fields omitted
}

impl SomeDataType {
    pub fn parse(text: &str) -> Result<SomeDataType, String> {
        let lines = text.lines().map(String::from).collect();
        Ok(SomeDataType { lines })
    }

    // replace first occurrence, and return original
    pub fn replace_placeholder(&mut self, real_value: &str) -> Option<String> {
        let newstr = format!("## {}", real_value);
        for line in self.lines.iter_mut() {
            if line.starts_with("## PLACEHOLDER") {
                let original = line.clone();
                *line = newstr;
                return Some(original);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```